# Printer prints in portrait even if print orientation is set to landscape

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, landscape

Tried to print an Excel spreadsheet. Printer prints in portrait even if print orientation is set to landscape.

Print orientation under preferences for printer setting is set to landscape.

Issue persists even if Print orientation for excel is also set to landscape as well.

In spite of all of the above, printer prints in portrait.

Comment: You might want to mention the printer model as well as excel and operating system versions.

Comment: Tried on XP.  and later Changed the PC and treied using Win 7.  same issue.

Comment: i would suggest trying a different printer to find out at which end the problem lies. and while they don't grow on trees, you can download one if you ain't got one handy :-) http://freepdfxp.de or http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/ are both free PDF Printers (software) you could use to try this. Btw. if the doc looks ok in the resulting pdf, try printing that. Might suck as a permanent workaround but as an option it might be ok.